# changing height of picture in grid.symbol function of grImport package

Tags: r, image, plot, ggplot2, grimport

I'm following this example from the [grImport package vignette page 15](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/vignettes/import.pdf):

```
R> xyplot(V8 ~ V7, data = flower,
+ xlab = "Height", ylab = "Distance Apart",
+ panel = function(x, y, ...) {
+ grid.symbols(PSflower, x, y, units = "native",
+ size = unit(5, "mm"))
+ })
```

Which essentially should plot a picture in a plot using certain coordinates:

[image]

My question: is it possible to adjust the height/width of the individual pictures?
This is possible if you use the `grid.picture` function using the `height` and `width` parameters, but I can't seem to find these parameters for `grid.symbols`. Can it be done using the `grid.symbols` function?

If not, is there anyway to plot in a coordinate based system using `grid.picture`?

Ultimately I would want something like:

[image]

Any help appreciated, thanks!